# Smallest Barcode Size?

Tags: barcode, barcode-printing

What is the smallest 1D barcode size I can print that will be readable by a scanner? Is 6mm x 6mm even possible?

I am planning to encode 21 characters. Will this fit into the barcode? If not will 2D do?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this depends on the printer and the scanner. The printer's resolution determines how legible the symbols are, so theoretically a 1200 dpi printer is going to print a more readable code than a 600 dpi. Of course that depends on software.

The scanner is limited by its field of "vision", so the closer the scanner can get to the substrate, the smaller your barcode can be. While a 6mm x 6mm target area is possible, you aren't going to get there with off-the-shelf products. Maybe using lenses (like a microscope) and a high fidelity printer (like a typesetter) you could get to 6mmx6mm, but it's going to be expensive.

The smallest I could get my software to do 21 characters is about 45mm using a HP Inkjet and Symbol handheld. However I was using Code128B. If you are using only numbers, Code128C would cut about 30% off the width.

http://brian-p-anderson.github.io/JS-Barcodes/